# Return dynamically generated SQL query in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to return what query is generated by executing a plpgsql.
How to achieve something like below?

```
do 
$$  
declare
sql_txt record;
tbl_nm text;
begin
tbl_nm := 'MyTable';
sql_txt:= 'select * from '||tbl_nm||';';
return  sql_txt;
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';`
```

I want the above run to return: select * from MyTable;

Comment: Anonymous `DO` blocks can not return anything. Shape your code as a function. Variable `sql_text` should be type `text` rather than `record`. You can also `raise notice '%', sql_txt;` in order to see the generated sql text.

Comment: you need something like https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-plpgsql/plpgsql-function-returns-a-table/  but a `SELECT *` is bad style

Comment: create function fn_return_sql_query() returns text as
$$ 
declare
sql_txt text;
tbl_nm text;
begin
 tbl_nm := 'MyTable';
  sql_txt:= 'select * from '||tbl_nm||';';
    return sql_txt;
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';
select fn_return_sql_query(); Thanks, this worked :-)

Comment: Add your code to your question text as properly formatted text .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function to return values, and [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to handle identifiers safely.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION fn_return_sql_query()
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   tbl_nm text := 'MyTable';
BEGIN
   RETURN format('SELECT * FROM %I;',  tbl_nm);
END
$func$;
```

The call `SELECT fn_return_sql_query();` produces:

```
SELECT * FROM "MyTable";
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lCoNQt1e)

Note the added double-quotes to preserve otherwise illegal spelling (upper case, leading digits, reserved words, ...) See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684)

Of course, you don't need `format()` for a *constant* table name. But the function only makes sense for dynamic input to begin with.